# SELECT * FROM NEW TABLE equivalent in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert

In DB2 I can do a command that looks like this to retrieve information from the inserted row:

```
SELECT *
FROM NEW TABLE (
    INSERT INTO phone_book
    VALUES ( 'Peter Doe','555-2323' )
) AS t
```

How do I do that in Postgres?

There are way to retrieve a sequence, but I need to retrieve arbitrary columns.

My desire to merge a select with the insert is for performance reasons.  This way I only need to execute one statement to insert values and select values from the insert.  The values that are inserted come from a subselect rather than a values clause.  I only need to insert 1 row.

That sample code was lifted from [Wikipedia Insert Article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insert_(SQL))

Comment: don't understand what's the performance reason leading you try to select and insert in one command. In my opinion, you should submit commit for insert operation before select.

Comment: @ParisTao: A single command (returning the correct row including auto-generated content like a serial ID) is simplest and fastest and *safest*. One might also want to INSERT / UPDATE more rows (like child rows in other tables referencing the ID) *before* committing all of it (or nothing).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A plain [`INSERT ... RETURNING ...`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-insert.html) does the job and delivers *best performance*.
A CTE is not necessary.

```
INSERT INTO phone_book (name, number)
VALUES ( 'Peter Doe','555-2323' )
RETURNING *  -- or just phonebook_id, if that's all you need
```

Aside: In most cases it's advisable to add a target list.

The [Wikipedia page you quoted](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insert_%28SQL%29#Retrieving_the_key) already has the same advice:

> Using an INSERT statement with RETURNING clause for PostgreSQL (since
>   8.2). The returned list is identical to the result of a SELECT.

Answer (score 2):

PostgreSQL supports this kind of behavior through a `returning` clause in a common table expression. You generally shouldn't assume that something like this will improve performance simply because you're executing one statement instead of two. [Use EXPLAIN](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-explain.html) to measure performance.

```
create table test (
  test_id serial primary key,
  col1 integer
);

with inserted_rows as (
  insert into test (c1) values (3)
  returning *
)
select * from inserted_rows;
```

```
test_id  col1
--
1        3
```

[Docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html)